# How to gracefully disable a PHP logging class

Tags: php

So i've got this logger (actually a wrapper), which is accessed all over the app with `Log::getInstance()->log_this` or `->log_that`, etc.  There is a config param in an ini which turns logging off, but the implementation to disable LogWrapper isn't quite right:

```
private function __construct() {
    if(config::get('logging_enabled')) {
            $this->logger = new Log();
        } 
        //else?
}

public static function getInstance() {
    if(self::$_instance == NULL) {
        self::$_instance = new LogWrapper();
    }
    return self::$_instance;
}
```

Calls to `getInstance()->any_method` delegate to the $logger instance, but will fail because $logger isn't anything.

Where can i stop this flow **within this class**?  It's not an option to modify the Log class, nor can i go through each call in the app to LogWrapper.  I can't seem to get my head around this, and  I know one smartly-placed line would fix it...

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not implement a dummy logger-class, that wouldn't log anything ?

And, then, instanciate either `Log` or that dummy-useless class, depending on the configuration :

```
if(config::get('logging_enabled')) {
    $this->logger = new Log();
} 
else {
    $this->logger = new DummyLogThatDoesntLog();
}
```

Comment: Yea that was one option, but i didn't want to create another class.

Comment: Well, in order to be able to call functions, you need an object, instance of a class that implements your Log interface ; I don't think you have much of a choice, if you don't want to change other parts of your code.

Comment: Yea the app is expecting an object with those methods-- i was hoping there was some trick to faking it!

Comment: If you're going to do this, make sure both classes implement an interface so the class structures dont diverge.